# FirebaseError - messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Okey here is the deal, I have asked a couple of firebase related question already in Stackoverflow, and even without any answers I managed to get firebase working, and received a bunch of notifications. I really don't know what I did to make it work, it was a combination of lots of things.

(Related issues posted earlier: [How to include firebase cloud messaging into ReactJS project using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319660/how-to-include-firebase-cloud-messaging-into-reactjs-project-using-webpack) | [Firebase FCM with ReactJS and Webpack not working: We are unable to register the default service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227458/firebase-fcm-with-reactjs-and-webpack-not-working-we-are-unable-to-register-the))

Anyhow, now it is not working again. I tried to simplify some configurations etc. and I broke the service-worker.

Now when I am trying to register the default firebase service-worker, I get the following error. When I type localhost:8000/firebase-messsaging-sw.js into my address bar, the file opens up though.

[image]

The thing that mystifies me is that "window is not defined error" since I have no idea why it is giving that. When I open up the file where it is coming from, I get this line of code:

[image: line_of_code_of_the_error]

Notice that I have the firebase-messaging-sw.js file running as a worker there, and opening that file opens a bunch of code, so something is registered by firebase.

WHAT I AM ASKING IS: How do I get rid of these firebase/messaging cannot register the default service worker errors, and that window is not defined error, and get FCM running stable?

Comment: i think you were missing sw.js file. Both file required for your web application `firebase-messaging-sw.js` and `service-worker.js`.

Comment: I think not since I got this running with only the firebase-messaging-sw.js file. But anyway thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem (again without any answers..). I needed to downgrade webpack-dev-server from 2.11.1 to 2.11.0! I am hoping that this might help someone else having this issue.

Comment: Haven't done angular in ages so if the issue is related to anything angular I can't help. For me the key things that helped me was to use a very specific webpack-dev-server version, and I had ot manually register the firebase-messaging-sw.js file because for some reason the default registration always failed. Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: PS. You'll find the guide to how to manually register your own service worker file in the firebase docs!